# Failed To Found: Gradle DSL method not found: 'complite()'

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement the new Cloud Firestore database in a project that already uses Firebase features, including Realtime Database - which I want to "upgrade".

I'm working according to this guide, but I'm getting stuck at compiling the Cloud Firestore library.
**This is my current project gradle:**
Project Gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

enter image description hereandroid {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapp.mealplanner"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }
productFlavors {
   }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.0.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
compite 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The project works fine, but when I try to add the Firebase dependence, Picasso and Firebase UI. It's error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: There is a type: compite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

Instead of

```
compite 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

it should be

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot really. It helped.